# Failed to assign variable taken from database to json array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I try to get the data from database to display data via ajax but failed to worked. It's partially working because data from mysql make this thing failed to function.

Here is my `funds_transfer_backend.php` page. This page will assign variable to json array.

```
session_start(); 

if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername']))
{
    header("Location: ../index.html");
    die();
}
            include("../connect.php");

            $myusername = $_SESSION['myusername'];

            $sql="SELECT client_id FROM `client` WHERE username='$myusername'";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){

            $id = $row['0'];  
            }    



            $index_num = $_POST['index_num'];
            $to_account_num = $_POST['recipient'];
            $amount = $_POST['amount'];

            if ($amount == '' || $to_account_num == '' || $index_num == -1){
                //echo "Please complete the form!";
                $response = -1;
            }

            else {  

             // check account number exist
            $query2 = "SELECT 1 FROM account WHERE id='$to_account_num' LIMIT 1";
            if (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, $query2))!=1) {
                 //echo "Recipient account number is invalid!";
                $response = -2;
            }   

            else {

            $query2 = "SELECT client.name, client.email FROM account JOIN client USING (client_id) WHERE account.id = '$to_account_num' LIMIT 1";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 

                $name = $row['name'];
                $email = $row['email'];

            } 
            $response = 1;

            }
            } // check account num else bracket

        $display = array('response' => $response, 'name' => $name);
        echo json_encode($display);
```

However if I remove `'name' => $name` from array the `#stage` div will trigger like image below:
[image]

Here is my `funds_transfer.php` page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function update() {
      var    two = $('#index_num').val();
      var    three = $('#recipient_box').val();
      var    five = $('#amount_box').val();


 $.post("funds_transfer_backend.php", { 
    index_num   : two,
    recipient   : three, 
    amount      : five

},function(data){


    if (data.response==-1) { 
        $('#stage').show().html("Please complete the form!"); 
    }

        $('#stage').delay(2000).fadeOut();


},"json");

        } 

</script>

...other code goes here

     <div id="stage" style="background-color:#FF6666; padding-left:20px; color: white;"></div>

     <div id="confirm" style="background-color:#FF7800; padding-left:20px; color: white;"></div>
```

I try to check the data from db whether it exist using manual form `method="post"` and I can see the name being echo. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your response is `-1`, your `$name` variable is undefined. So php could show a warning (depending on your settings) and you are trying to add an undefined variable to your array. This will invalidate your output / json.

You can set for example:

```
$name = '';
```

at the start of your script or check whether the variable is set with `isset($name)` before you try to use it to avoid these problems.

There are of course other solutions, like outputting your `-1` directly and exiting the script there.

Comment: That's solved the problem. Thank you very much. I thought when you say `-1` the problem is the number is `negative` but it is something else right?

Comment: @sg552 It is not about the number but about the `if` condition; where you set the number to `-1` you are not setting the name, only in the `else` section.

Answer (score 1):

I always initialize my variables.

$myusername = isset($_SESSION['myusername']) ? $_SESSION['myusername'] : false;

Then you can safely do:

if ($myusername) {} without throwing warnings.

I do this weather I get my data from a db, post/get/session or json/ajax.

It takes a little extra time upfront but removes dozens of errors in the back end so you net more time.